# Comparing query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

So I'm getting a table/view name or a SQL query as input and I need to apply a `WHERE` filtering on it. Since parsing the query for an already-existing `WHERE` clause could be quite some work, I thought I'd be better off enclosing the incoming query into an *umbrella* `SELECT` and append `WHERE` with it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (<ORIGINAL_QUERY_OR_TABLE_NAME>) WHERE <CONDITION>
```

I suspected this could possibly introduce performance penalties since I have now created a sub-query, so I went ahead and create execution plans for the original query and the modified version. I now have two plans in front of me, but I'm not sure how to compare them. The nodes shown in both plans are same and the costs are shown as percentage of the parent query, not as some absolute number to let me compare the two.

So my questions are:

1. Am I really doing this the good way; i.e. with no performance hits?
2. How do I compare the two execution plans?

Note: This is SQL Server 2008 R2.

**Edit**

For people wondering why I didn't simply append the filtering clause with `AND <CONDITION>` to the incoming query by testing for the existing of the string `WHERE`, note that it ain't all that simple. Consider the following queries:

```
1. SELECT * FROM MyTable
2. SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField = 123
3. SELECT [WHAT], [WHEN], [WHERE] FROM MyTable
4. SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY [WHERE]
```

Comment: Why dont uyou use SET STATISTICS ON with TIME and IO option on to check which query takes how much time?

Comment: @PareshJ: Very helpful indeed. The time difference between the two queries is minimal. For 60K rows, the two queries used **2032ms** and **2103ms** respectively, so I guess I'm pretty safe here.

Comment: Keep in mind that measuring performance is almost always harder than it looks. Did you clear the caches before running each test?

Comment: @HABO: No. How do I do that? Any other things that you recommend I should be doing before measurements?

Comment: From a quick Google! search for `sql server clear cache` is [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10818/sql-server-commands-to-clear-caches-before-running-a-performance-comparison) article. It's a place to start. You also need to define the target context, e.g. will the query be compiled once and reused frequently or recompiled each time? Will the caches typically contain data useful for the query, e.g. from a recent execution or other DB activity? Would adding an index be a net win or loss given expected writes? A covering index? More memory? Increased parallelism? More coffee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see relative performance difference between 2 queries, you can run both (or more) of your queries in one query and in actual execution plan you will see a percentage that each query took.

For example, if you see 50% for first query and 50% for second, this indicates the query performance is identical. In this case you might even see that execution plan is identical. If you see that one query has much higher percentage than the other, you can start looking what part of the query took the longest.

Comment: mmmm... shouldn't have missed that. hold on.

Comment: Very helpful. They are showing 50% each. So I assume SQL Server is internally optimizing it somehow.